# Ajax Request with Shopify App (PHP template)

Tags: php, reactjs, shopify

Actually I'm developing an application on Shopify using PHP/REACT and I need to make an AJAX call to fetch data from my controller (not an external API).

For that, and also for following I'm using a tunnel for my localhost, as suggested in the Shopify doc, but when I try to make the call I'm getting an error of missing host parameter (which is mandatory for Shopify) and if I add that parameter, I get redirected to my app's homepage in Shopify like if it was an installation.

I'm not sure if it's related to the tunnel or will it be possible to make ajax calls if I use a true domain without tunnels.

Does anyone knows how to do internal API calls in Shopify apps when we're in development stage using PHP ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, you just need to add you route (when it's a POST request) to web/app/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php in the $exception attribute

```
protected $except = [
        'api/graphql',
        'api/webhooks',
        'my/route'
    ];
```